# javascript array sorting?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following array:

```
var things = ['sandwich', 17, 'fake@sample.com', 3, 'horse', 'octothorpe', 'anotheremail@sample.com', '!invalid_garbage@sample.com'];
```

Sort the array into three others, one of numbers, one of strings, and one of valid email addresses. Discard the invalid address.

Comment: Do the resulting arrays have to be sorted themselves..?

Comment: @Josh, or at the very least *tag* it as homework...also, how are we supposed to make an array of three numbers from two?

Comment: What is the difference between an invalid email and a string? Which one is `'horse'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var emails = [], strings = [], numbers = [];

things.forEach(function (e) {
    if (typeof e == "string") {

        if (e.indexOf("@") != -1) { // "looks" like an email if it contains @
           if (isEmail(e)) emails.push(e); // push if it is a valid email
        }

        else strings.push(e);
    }

    else if (typeof e == "number") {
       numbers.push(e);
    }
 });

function isEmail(str) { return /** true if str is a valid email **/ }
```

I'll leave it up to you to come up with a correct `isEmail` function.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use the filter function of the Array object.

Example:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {  
  return (element >= 10);  
}  
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
```

You need to write 3 custom filtering functions for each of your needed arrays.

The first two conditions are trivial, as for the third one I recommend choosing a regexp that satisfies your exigence in validating emails. A short one would be `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$`.

Regards,
Alin

Comment: +1 Good answer. gives the OP enough to go on without giving it to him on a plate.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(arr) {
    var a = [], b = [], c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === "number") {
            a.push(arr[i]);
        } else if (isValidEmail(arr[i])) {
            b.push(arr[i]);
        } else if (typeof arr[i] === "string") {
            c.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return [a, b, c];
}());
```

isValidEmail(s) returns true if the the argument is a string representing a valid e-mail. You are best of using a RegEx for this...

BTW, the way you use this is, you assign the above expression to a variable, and then this variable holds the three arrays as its items...

Comment: You assigned a, b, c to the same array. You need to assign each a new instance of an array otherwise you're pushing to the same array in memory.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one solution

```
function isBigEnough(el, i, array) {  
  return (el >= 10);  
}  
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
```

Try this.